# What is the most natural value of Heaviside step function at zero argument?

Tags: dirac-delta-distributions, conventions

In many physical applications, the Heaviside step fuction is defined as $$H(x) = \left\{\begin{eqnarray}
1, \quad x>0 \\
0, \quad x<0
\end{eqnarray}\right.$$
The value $H(0)$ is left undefined. Is there a physically prefered value of $H(0)$ or does it depend on the problem at hand?

For example, due to relation $H'(x) = \delta(x)$, it would be nice to have $H(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ if we think of $\delta(x)$ as an even function. However, when considering signal processing, we would like our functions to be (left/right) continuous at $x=0$.

Is there a way out of this arbitrariness?

Comment: "Is there a way out of this arbitrariness?" Nope. Depends on context.

Comment: I usually see $H(0) \equiv 1/2$

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173811/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Continuous [Fourier analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis), which contains both the Fourier transform and the Fourier series, and which is used in e.g. [signal processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis#Applications_in_signal_processing), naturally picks the average value of the left and right limits, cf. the [Dini-Dirichlet criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence). For the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Zero_argument), this means that

$$ H(0)~=~\frac{1}{2} \left(\lim_{x\to 0^-} H(x)+ \lim_{x\to 0^+} H(x)\right) ~=~\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}.\tag{1}$$

The Fourier transform of the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) $H(x)$ is the [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))

$$\widehat{H}(k)~=~\int_{\mathbb{R}}\! dx e^{-ikx} H(x) ~=~\frac{-i}{k-i0^+},\tag{2} $$

or conversely

$$ H(x)~=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\! \frac{dk}{2\pi} e^{ikx} \widehat{H}(k) ~=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\! \frac{dk}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{ikx}}{k-i0^+}.\tag{3} $$

As a check, setting $x=0$ in eq. (3) yields precisely eq. (1),

$$ H(x=0) ~\stackrel{(3)}{=}~\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\frac{dk}{2\pi i} \frac{1}{k-i0^+}~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\! \frac{dk}{2\pi i}\left( P\frac{1}{k} + i\pi\delta(k)\right) ~=~\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}, \tag{4} $$

cf. the [Sokhotski–Plemelj formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem)

$$ \frac{1}{k-i0^+}~=~P\frac{1}{k} +i\pi\delta(k). \tag{5}$$

Comment: Where can I find the full versions of the Fourier transforms? Wikipedia does not list the full form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean I want the table of Fourier transforms that does not hide the infinite terms and works everywhere. For instance, I want $$\widehat H(x+a)=~PV\frac{-i}{k} +\pi\delta(k)+ a\operatorname {sinc} \left({\frac {k a }{2\pi}}\right)$$ instead of $$H(x+a)\to -\frac{i e^{i a k} }{k}+\pi  \delta (k)$$ which they give in the tables.

Comment: Where you got the (2)?

Answer (score 0):

For analytical calculations, you just can't use $H(0)$ because it is not defined there. Also, you don't need it.

For numerical calculations, situations where a more continuous function might be of advantage; in physics, people often use the [Fermi-Dirac distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics#Fermi.E2.80.93Dirac_distribution) (which converges to a Heaviside function for $T=0$; you could call it a Heaviside sequence, analogous to a [Delta sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)), also for situations which have no connection with statistical physics. In this case, you would also define $H(0)=1/2$.

There are other sequences/approximations at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Analytic_approximations). I think that they all define $H(0)=1/2$.

Comment: It's not true that you don't need it for analytical calculations. Particle path integrals in curved spaces produce integrals of the form $$\int_0^1 d\tau \int_0^1 d\sigma \,  \theta(\tau-\sigma) \delta(\tau-\sigma) \, ...$$ are present.