# Fourier Transforms Related to Green's Functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fourier-transform

I'm reading a text on field theory where there are a number of assertions made about Fourier transforms that I'm finding confusing. For example, let $G^R = -i \theta(t - t')e^{-i \omega_0 (t - t')}$. The text says that the FT of $G^R$ wtih respect to $t-t'$ is $(\epsilon - \omega_0 + i0)^{-1}$. What is the meaning of this $i0$ term?

Secondly, after inverting this expression the text takes the inverse transform. That is, the inverse FT of $\epsilon - \omega_0 + i0$ and obtains $\delta(t - t')(i\partial_{t'} - \omega_0 + i0)$. What is the meaning of this? How did the fourier transform of an expression become an operator?

Thanks!

Comment: The Fourier transform of $G^R$ does not converge, unless you put in a regularization term $e^{-\eta t}$ where $\eta$ is taken to $0$ in the end of the calculation. Then you get $\epsilon-\omega_0+i\eta$. So $0$ here really means an infinitesimally small positive number. For the inverse transform, you need to do the complex integral using residue theorem and you will see $i0$ determines how you close the contour.

Comment: Thanks. I see what is being done in the FT now. Can you explain the inverse FT in more depth?

Comment: What I said was not entirely right. $i0$ means that the pole of the integrand is in the upper half plane. If $t>t'$, then you have to close your contour also in the upper half plane and then picks up a nonzero reside. If $t<t'$ the contour is closed in the lower half plane and no poles are enclosed, so you get zero. Therefore $i0$ gives you exactly the causal structure $\theta(t-t')$.

Answer (score 4):

In essence, you are taking the Fourier transform of the Heaviside theta function, $\theta(t)$, to try and get
$$
\tilde\theta(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\omega t}\theta(t)\text dt=\int_{0}^\infty e^{i\omega t}\text dt.
$$
For nonzero $\omega$, this is perfectly fine and easily evaluates to ${1}/{i\omega}$ once you discard the term at infinity (which is also not easy!). For $\omega=0$, however, that result is obviously bogus, and the bare integral $\int_{0}^\infty 1\text dt$ also makes no sense.

To bring both of those problems into line, the usual approach is to employ a regularization procedure: introduce an exponential decay $e^{-\epsilon t}$ into the integrand, to force convergence at $\omega=0$ and to get rid of the $e^{i\omega·\infty}$ term, and then take the limit of $\epsilon\to 0$. This means that, when we talk about $\tilde\theta$, we're actually talking about
$$
\tilde\theta(\omega)
=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{0}^\infty e^{i\omega t-\epsilon t}\text dt
=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{-i}{\omega+i\epsilon}.
$$
This notation is often contracted to the shorthand 
$$
\tilde\theta(\omega)=\frac{-i}{\omega+i0},
$$
where the term in $+i0$ stands for an infinitesimally small, but positive, imaginary part. This imaginary part comes in when integrating over $\omega$: it means that the ugly pole at $\omega=0$ should be displaced down before integration, which can be done quite easily in practice via the [Sokhotski formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem#Version_for_the_real_line). This integration is important because often, in the end, what we actually want from $\tilde\theta$ is that it reproduce the time-domain function,
$$
\theta(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega t}\tilde\theta(\omega)\text d\omega,
$$
so if it has non-integrable singularities it also needs to be equipped with instructions on how to deal with them.

---

If you want to get a bit more technical, both $\theta(t)$ and $\tilde\theta(\omega)$ are best thought of as [*distributions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29) rather than functions, and the maths there can get a bit subtle. Essentially, a distribution is an object $D$ which (only?) makes sense when inside an integral, i.e. as 
$$\int D(x) f(x) \mathrm d x$$
for some unknown, suitably nice, function $f$. ([Ring a bell?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)) More formally, $D$ is really shorthand notation for a *functional* which takes functions into numbers, i.e. for the mapping 
$$f\mapsto\int D(x) f(x) \mathrm d x.$$

One easy way to get distributions is to simply make $D$ a function. Even better, if $D$ is in [$L^1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) then its distribution-sense Fourier transform is just its normal transform. If $D$ is not in $L^1$ (say it stays constant, or grows linearly, at large $x$), then it won't have a Fourier transform in the traditional sense, but [it can still have a transform in a suitable distributional sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform), which opens the way to using the Fourier transform in a much broader range of interesting cases, at the minor cost that the end result is again a distribution.

This is actually what's happening in both of the examples you mention. Here $\theta(t)$ and $1/\tilde\theta(\omega)=-(\omega+i0)$ stay constant, and grow linearly, at large arguments, so they wouldn't normally be given Fourier transforms. In the distributional sense, however, this is indeed valid, and their transforms
$$
\tilde\theta(\omega)=\frac{-i}{\omega+i0}
$$
and
$$
\widetilde{1/\tilde\theta}(t)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\omega e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm d\omega=\delta(t)\partial_t
$$
are perfectly valid distributions - i.e. they make perfect sense when applied on some function $f$ and integrated over.

Answer (score 3):

1. $i0$ is meant as
   $$\frac{1}{\epsilon - \omega_0 + i 0} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{\epsilon - \omega_0 + i x}\, . $$
   The idea here is that the Fourier transform of something containing a theta function is not well defined. This comes from the fact that the integral
   $$ G(\epsilon) = -i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \theta(\tau) \text{e}^{-i \tau (\omega_0-\epsilon)} = -i \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{e}^{-i \tau (\omega_0-\epsilon)} \, ,$$
   does not converge. However, if you add any positive imaginary part to $\epsilon \rightarrow \epsilon + i x$, it converges for all $x>0$. As long as $x>0$ all our integrals converge,
   $$ G(\epsilon+ix) = -i \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{e}^{-i \tau (\omega_0-\epsilon)} \, \text{e}^{-\tau x} = -\frac{1}{\omega_0-\epsilon-ix}\, .$$
   At the end of the calculation, we can therefore take $x$ as small as we want and it drops out of the final result. The sign of $x$ however is very important. If you take a negative $x$ and Fourier transform back, you will find the same $G(\tau)$ as before with the only difference that $\theta(\tau)$ is now $\theta(-\tau)$. This means that your response function $G(\tau)$ now responds to something that will happen in the future. Choosing $x>0$ is a means to enforce causality to response functions.
2. As before, the Fourier transform of $\epsilon$ leads to an integral that does not converge,
   $$G(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d \epsilon \, \text{e}^{-i\tau\epsilon} \epsilon \, .$$
   You can however write it formally as
   $$G(\tau) = i\frac{d}{d\tau} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\epsilon \, \text{e}^{-i\tau\epsilon} = i\frac{d}{d\tau} \delta(\tau)\, .$$
   $\delta(\tau)$ is the delta distribution, $\delta(\tau\neq 0) = 0$, $\delta(0) = \infty$, $\int \delta(\tau) = 1$. You cannot really interpret it as a function, but it makes a perfect operator acting on functions,
   $$(\delta f)(x) \equiv \int d y \, \delta(y-x) f(y) = f(0) \, .$$
   The same happens with its derivative and you recover the expression from your book.

Answer (score 1):

The $\mathrm{i}0$ is short for
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\mathrm{i}\epsilon$$
and is used in the so-called $\mathrm{i}\epsilon$-prescription. It is necessary for some integrals so that the contour does not hit a pole and render the integral ill-defined. In this case, you must insert $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\mathrm{e}^{-x\epsilon}$ into your Fourier transform so that the integral converges. Note that the notation of your book is confusing -- it uses $\epsilon$ for the transform variable while $\epsilon$ is standard notation for the infinitesimal in $\mathrm{i}0$.

I think that you misread the text for the inverse transform. It should be $(\mathrm{i}\partial_{t'}-\omega_0+\mathrm{i}0)\delta(t-t')$, i.e. the derivative is acting on the delta function. Using the integral representation of the delta function, 
$$\delta(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx}$$
we find that the inverse Fourier transform of a constant (note that $\omega_0$ and $\mathrm{i}0$ are just constants) is proportional to a delta function. You may also verify that the derivative of the integral representation of the delta function is proportional to the inverse Fourier transform of the time variable.