# Feynman propagator at equal times

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, propagator

In [Timo Weigand's lecture notes](https://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/courses/weigand/QFT1-12-13.pdf) on page 36, Equation $(1.165)$, he defines the Feynman propagator (free scalar field theory):

$D_F(x-y)$ := $\langle 0|T\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle \tag{1}$

This means $(1)$ should **either** be $\langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle \hspace{2mm}\text{or}\hspace{2mm} \langle 0|\phi(y) \phi(x)|0 \rangle \tag{2}$

In the next lines, he $D_F(x-y)$ as:

$D_F(x-y) = \Theta(x^0 - y^0) \langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle + \Theta(y^0 - x^0) \langle 0|\phi(y) \phi(x)|0 \rangle \tag{3}$

To preserve causality in QFT, $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ should commute if $x$ and $y$ are spacelike separated. Now, consider spacetime points (events) $x$ and $y$ such that $x^0 = y^0$. This means that these events are obviously spacelike separated. Therefore $(3)$ becomes:

$\Theta(0) \hspace{1mm} \langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle + \Theta(0) \hspace{1mm} \langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle  = 2\langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle \tag{4}$

So the only way for $(2)$ and $(4)$ to be agreed with each other is when:

$\langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle = \langle 0|\phi(y) \phi(x)|0 \rangle = 0$

Even if the $\Theta(0)$ is defined to be $0$, then too the above equality   should hold to make $(2)$ and $(4)$ agree with each other.

With the above observations, is the following statement correct?: The Feynman propagator, $D_F(x-y)$ vanishes when $x^0 = y^0$

Comment: The [value of the Heaviside function at zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Zero_argument) is *not* necessarily 1. It is common to choose $\Theta(0) = 1/2$ or even $\Theta(0) = 0$, or to conceive of it purely as a distribution with no value at zero at all (like the Dirac delta).

Comment: Related: [What is the most natural value of Heaviside step function at zero argument?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61176/2451)

Comment: When $x^0=y^0$, the propagator need not be zero (and in fact is not zero) when $x^i=y^i$. Usually the propagator is singular there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $D_F(x-y) = \Theta(x^0 - y^0) \langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle + \Theta(y^0 - x^0) \langle 0|\phi(y) \phi(x)|0 \rangle \tag{3}$

> ... this means that these events are obviously spacelike separated. Therefore $(3)$ becomes:

> $\Theta(0)\hspace{1mm} \langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle + \Theta(0) \hspace{1mm} \langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle  = 2\langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle \tag{4A}$

No, using $\Theta(0)=1/2$, it becomes:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \hspace{1mm} \langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle + \frac{1}{2} \hspace{1mm} \langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle  = \langle 0|\phi(x) \phi(y)|0 \rangle \tag{4B}
$$
$$
=\langle 0|\phi(t,\vec x) \phi(t, \vec y)|0 \rangle
=\langle 0|\phi(t, \vec y) \phi(t, \vec x)|0 \rangle
$$