# Dimensionality of a Hilbert Space: Countable or Uncountable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

(My question is different than [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64869/hilbert-space-of-harmonic-oscillator-countable-vs-uncountable) and [the similar one about the free particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65457/2451), so hold back on casting a close vote, please).

So, I was reading on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac%E2%80%93von_Neumann_axioms), and ran into this statement in the Dirac-von Neumann axioms: *The space $\mathbb{H}$ is a fixed complex Hilbert space of **countable infinite dimension.***

This is rather confusing to me; I use position and momentum as bases for this Hilbert space all the time, and those bases have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. How is it that the space is countably infinite when we use uncountable basis sets to perform basic calculations?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98723/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a particle on an infinite line, position and momentum eigenstates are not a true basis for the Hilbert space; they aren't even *in* the Hilbert space.  They are useful computational tools, but complications and contradictions can arise if you pretend that they are genuine states.  To treat them properly requires the [rigged Hilbert space](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4958725) formalism.

$L^2(\mathbb R)$ is indeed separable, however - the weighted Hermite polynomials (which are incidentally the eigenstates of the quantum harmonic oscillator) constitute a countable basis for it.