# Extending projection operator to infinite-dimensional case

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hilbert-space, notation, linear-algebra

Hi I have a basic question regarding bra-ket notation. Given that $\{|e_n \rangle \}$ is a discrete orthonormal basis, $$\langle e_m | e_n \rangle = \delta_{mn}$$ then $$\sum_{n}|e_n \rangle \langle e_n | ={\bf 1}$$ (the identity operator). This follows since we can easily show (by expressing any vector $v$ in component form) that $$\sum_n |e_n \rangle \langle e_n | v \rangle = | v \rangle.$$

When dealing with a inner product which has a continuous orthonormalized basis, it is stated that $$ \langle e_z | e_z' \rangle = \delta (z-z')$$ then $$\int | e_z \rangle \langle e_z| dz = {\bf 1}.$$

How would you show the last two equations? I think the first equation holds because we simply define the inner-product in this way and can show that it  is consistent with the properties of an inner-product.

Comment: You can't prove these relations: they are the **definition** of a continuous orthonormal basis.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Oh :| Are they simply defined in this way to be analogous to the finite dimensional case?

Comment: The objects $\lvert e_z\rangle$ are actually neither "orthonormal" nor a "basis", they don't lie inside the Hilbert space. Their rigorous theory requires the notion of [rigged Hilbert spaces](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43515/50583).

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64869/2451) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65457/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Comment: @Qmechanic Is it clear to you why
$\sum_{n}|e_n \rangle \langle e_n | ={\bf 1}$ and 
$\int | e_z \rangle \langle e_z| dz = {\bf 1}$ imply completeness?