# On different Hilbert spaces and energy spectra in the "Particle in a box" problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

## Disclaimer

In this question I suspect some of the used words are not precise so there is a possibility for misunderstanding here. If you know how to say more correctly or precisely - EDIT! Sorry in advance.

## Preliminaries

Consider a particle in the following 1D potential well
$$
U(x) =
\begin{cases}
    0, & x\in[0,b]\\
    V, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\tag{*}
\label{pot}
$$
(1st problem) If $V<\infty$ then there are both discrete and continuum spectra. So Hilbert space corresponding to this problem is *non-countably-infinite-dimensional*.

(2nd problem) But in the case of an infinite well potential there is only discrete spectrum, so Hilbert space is *countably-infinite-dimensional*. So these Hilbert spaces are different, not even isomorphic.

## Question

On the one hand, if one increases $V$ continuously (e.g. in time) in eq.\eqref{pot} the first problem becomes "closer", in some sence, to the second one. And we should (shouldn't we?) conclude that the second one is a limit for the first one. But, on the other hand, two problems are the same implies their Hilbert spaces are equal (maybe isomorphic). I am wondering

> How is it possible that a continuum transformed into a countable set (sorry
>   again) "continuously"?

## Update

What about the energy values?
Considering the first problem there are both discrete and continuum spectra:
$$
    E^{(1)} = \{E_i|i\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{E_\alpha|\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$
so $\mathrm{card}(E^{(1)})=\aleph_1$.
The energy spectrum in the second problem consists only of discrete values so
$\mathrm{card}(E^{(2)})=\aleph_0$. So how and where the continuum disappears when $V$ approaches to infinity?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64869/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65457/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

In both problems the Hilbert space is $L^2 (\mathbb R)$ which is an infinite-dimensional complex vector space and is separable, i.e. it has a countable basis (*Schauder basis*). The "(non)-countably-infinite-dimensional" phrase you use is imprecise. I assume you mean that the basis might be countable or not, case in which I said the Hilbert space has a countable Schauder basis.

I sense that you vaguely hint to the concept of rigged Hilbert spaces. A readable account of them is the textbook on Quantum Mechanics by Leslie Ballentine, or a more involved one is in the textbook by Galindo and Pascual (1st volume of the English edition published by Springer Verlag).