# Why do bound electrons have quantized energy states but free electrons can occupy any possible energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, discrete

Why do electrons have discrete energy states when they are bound to a nucleas and not when they are free for example in an electron beam. Why doesn't an electron beam have certain specified energies like bound electrons do.

Comment: Have you studied solutions to the Schrodinger equation for the [finite potential well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well)?

Comment: The boundary conditions of a bound electron (in for example an infinite potential well) are such that there are only certain integer energies allowed. You can check this in any introductory quantum mechanics text. No such conditions exist for a free electron.

Comment: Boundary conditions

Comment: Moiz you should say from what level of physics you ask, just a school kid or a student

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73394/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65636/2451 and links therein.