# Discontinuity of metric derivatives in the Israel junction formalism

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, boundary-conditions

It is often said that given the metrics $g^+$, $g^-$ on two sides of a hypersurface $\Sigma$, then, with a level-set function $\phi$ such that $\Sigma = \phi^{-1}(0)$, we can describe the metric on the whole manifold by

\begin{equation}
g = \theta(\phi) g^+ + (1 - \theta(\phi)) g^- \tag{1}
\end{equation}

And then, the derivatives of the components are simply

\begin{equation}
g_{ab,c} = \partial_c \theta(\phi) (g^+ - g^-) + \theta(\phi) g^+_{ab,c} + (1 - \theta(\phi)) g^-_{ab,c}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

and since it is assumed that $g$ is continuous,

\begin{equation}
g_{ab,c} = \theta(\phi) g^+_{ab,c} + (1 - \theta(\phi)) g^-_{ab,c}\tag{3}
\end{equation}

The discontinuity in the derivatives is then said to be

\begin{equation}
[g_{ab,c}] = \gamma_{ab} n_c\tag{4}
\end{equation}

for $n$ a normal form to $\Sigma$ and $\gamma_{ab}$ some tensor, and the notation corresponds to

\begin{equation}
[F] = \lim_{p \in M^+ \to \Sigma} F(p) - \lim_{p \in M^- \to \Sigma} F(p)\tag{5}
\end{equation}

The proof for this seems rather elusive, but according to [Clarke and Dray](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/4/2/010/), this stems from the fact that for $v$ some vector field such that $g(v, n) = 0$, with $n$ some extension of the normal form (I'm guessing via the normal bundle of the surface), we have

\begin{equation}
v^c[g_{ab,c}] = v^c [g_{ab}]_{,c} = 0\tag{6}
\end{equation}

which then implies that $[g_{ab,c}] = \gamma_{ab} n_c$. I'm not quite sure how to show this. Expanding everything, I get

\begin{equation}
(\lim_{p \in M^+ \to \Sigma} \theta v^c g^+_{ab,c} - \lim_{p \in M^- \to \Sigma} (1 - \theta) v^c g^-_{ab,c})\tag{7}
\end{equation}

given coordinates with tangent vectors $(n, \partial_\alpha)$, we can decompose this as

\begin{equation}
v^c g^\pm_{ab,c} = v^\alpha g^\pm_{ab,\alpha}\tag{8}
\end{equation}

since $v$ has no $n$ component. How to show that this quantity is then continuous upon crossing the boundary? Do I need to define the first fundamental form for every hypersurface $\Sigma_\varepsilon$ along the normal bundle of coordinate $\varepsilon$ and show that this is continuous?

Comment: Is $n$ assumed to be null? non-null?

Comment: This is for strictly timelike hypersurfaces, so $n$ is always spacelike.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, interestingly, the [Israel junction conditions](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=Israel+junction+conditions) are born out of mathematical necessity to avoid ill-defined products$^1$ of distributions rather than actual physical considerations. See e.g. Refs. 1 & 2 for details.

References:

1. Eric Poisson, *A Relativist's Toolkit,* 2004; Section 3.7.
2. Eric Poisson, [*An Advanced course in GR*](https://archive.org/details/Eric_Poisson__Advanced_general_relativity); Section 3.7.

--

$^1$ We ignore [Colombeau theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombeau_algebra). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47934/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 1):

I am you from the future. Here's a probably fine argument for this.

Take the normal bundle of the hypersurface $N = (-1, 1) \times \Sigma$, with the adapted coordinates $(r, y)$ such that $\partial_r$ is a vector normal to the hypersurface. We can decompose the metric tensor as

$$g = g(\partial_r, \partial_r) dr \otimes dr + g^r_{\Sigma}$$

where $g_{\Sigma, r}$ is the first fundamental form on the surface defined by the projection of the normal bundle at $r$. The derivative with respect to the $\Sigma$ coordinates at $r = \varepsilon$

$$\partial_c \bar g^\varepsilon_{ab} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{ \bar g^\varepsilon_{ab}(x + h) - \bar g^\varepsilon_{ab}(x)}{h}$$

The discontinuity is then gonna be

$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \lim_{h \to 0} [\frac{ \bar g^\varepsilon_{ab}(x + h) - \bar g^\varepsilon_{ab}(x) - \bar g^{-\varepsilon}_{ab}(x + h) + \bar g^{-\varepsilon}_{ab}(x)}{h} ]$$

I think we can assume uniform convergence ($g$ should be bounded on the neighbourhood), in which case we can switch the limits and, since $g$ is continuous,

\begin{eqnarray}
[\partial_c g_{ab}] &=& \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}  [\frac{ \bar g^\varepsilon_{ab}(x + h) - \bar g^\varepsilon_{ab}(x) - \bar g^{-\varepsilon}_{ab}(x + h) + \bar g^{-\varepsilon}_{ab}(x)}{h} ] \\
&=& \lim_{h \to 0} [\frac{ \bar g^0_{ab}(x + h) - \bar g^0_{ab}(x) - \bar g^0_{ab}(x + h) + \bar g^{0}_{ab}(x)}{h} ]\\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}

Since $v$ only depends on this part of the metric, we have indeed $v^\sigma [g_{\mu\nu,\sigma}] = 0$.