# Extending Geodesic Across Boundary in Discontinuous Spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, boundary-conditions, geodesics

Imagine a metric space to be discontinuous: a [Schwarzschild outer metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric#Formulation) that changes to a flat [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) once inside the boundary of a $2$-sphere of fixed $r$. If an object (or ray) just hitting the boundary at $r=R$ from the outside has its own four velocity, then in order to continue it, one would have to find the FLRW version of the vector at $r=$R. So the trajectory would be discontinuous. What I want to know is how to find that corresponding vector.

All I know is that it involves the tensor $h_{ab}$, which I don't know the name of. But I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What reference talks about $h_{ab}$?

Comment: I don’t think “discontinuous spacetimes” are mainstream physics.

Comment: The question seems underspecified since the FLRW metric is time-dependent and you don’t specify what time it’s supposed to be when you cross the boundary.

Comment: @Ghoster:  These are known as "thin-shell" metrics and are well-studied in GR.  The idea is that you can model the boundary between two "smooth" metrics as containing a "thin shell" of stress-energy, similarly to how surface charges & surface currents create discontinuous EM fields.  For more details, see Poisson's *A Relativist's Toolkit* among other sources.

Comment: $h_{ab}$ is usually called the "induced metric" on the boundary hypersurface.

Comment: @Ghoster: You're right, I didn't specify the $t$ value at the boundary. Also, the other thing is the scale factor, which I don't want to be just $t$ because I want to avoid singularities. So then I guess $e^t$.

Comment: @Michael Seifert: One thing that confuses me is: when it is written with Greek indices, doesn't that undermine the inducedness? Anyway, I think that for the purpose of extending the geodesic in this case it would be the induced metric on the 2-sphere surface only, with $r$ as the ambient space.

Comment: @Ghoster: Here is the reference. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.3793.pdf

Comment: This answer might be interesting to you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/480194/27732. A keyword you might find useful is the "Israel Junction Conditions".

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks for the info about this topic.

Comment: @Andrew: The second answer says that the two conditions are that the extrinsic curvature and induced metric on the boundary must be the same on both sides of it. However, I still don't understand how to get the induced metric.